# How to togglebutton cliked change in widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want the Column widget in my code to change when the inside presses the togglebutton.

I try:

```
if(index==0){},if(index==1){}
```

it can't change.

final `isSelected = <bool>[true, false, false, false];`

```
onPressed: (index) {
    setState(() {
        for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
            isSelected[i] = i == index;
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  ToggleButtons()

Comment: (Even with the code layout improved, I can't make head or tail of your question. You added a comment with what looks like code: Edit your question instead. While at it, review the title. (*cliked*?))

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
onPressed: (index) {
    setState(() {
        for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
            isSelected[i] = false;
        }
        isSelected[index]=true; // update your selected index to true
    });
},
```